# Creating a GWT widget that others can embed in their website?

Tags: javascript, gwt, iframe

I've created a widget in GWT and I would like to be able to give users a small snippet of HTML that they can embed in their website so my widget will be rendered there.

I don't believe an iframe would be appropriate as one requirement is that clicking any links on my widget should take the user to my website (not just change the content of the iframe).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I tried embedding the following, but no luck:
< script src="http://embeddedapptest.appspot.com/embeddedapp/embeddedapp.nocache.js" >< /script >
< div id="foo" / >

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. The snippet will need to be like

```
<script src="yourmodule.nocache.js"></script>
<div id="foo"/>
```

Then in your entry point do this:

```
RootPanel root = RootPanel.get("foo");
// add your things here. root.add(...);
```

You will need to be careful not to step on the outer page's styling and vice versa but compiled CSS should go a long way to helping that.

This is the technique used to embed an APIs Explorer in Google APIs documentation.

Comment: I've tried this, but I can't get it to work.  I've deployed an app at http://embeddedapptest.appspot.com/.  This is implemented exactly as you suggest above.  I then embed the following html in another site, but no luck:
<script src="http://embeddedapptest.appspot.com/embeddedapp/embeddedapp.nocache.js"></script>
<div id="foo"/>
What am I doing wrong?  Does it work for you?

Comment: Ok, it's not showing the whole of my script tag, so I've included it in my main question above

Comment: Try adding <add-linker name="xsiframe"> to your module gwt xml

Comment: note jason wrote that you need to include the html entry point, not the .js file

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Include the nocache.js just as if you were using it in your own site.

Comment: I added the xsiframe tag and it now shows the button. Thanks! However, when i click the button the server requests are still failing with the following error.  Any ideas?

/embeddedapp/greet
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission accessDeclaredMembers)
 at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:355)
 at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:567)
 at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
...

Comment: P.S. I'm seeing this error on the embedded app server, not on the user's, so they're definitely reaching the right server

Comment: I guess this makes sense as this would be cross-site scripting.  So perhaps a better question is: how can i populate my app with data if I can't contact my server?

Comment: P.S. full stack trace is available here: http://embeddedapptest.appspot.com/fullstacktrace.txt

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? The stack trace looks like you might be trying to upload to the App Engine Blob store. I don't think that works cross-domain...

Comment: None of those stack frames are my code.  The server has one class with one method, but the error is thrown before it gets there:
@Override
 public String greetServer(String input) throws IllegalArgumentException
 {
  return input;
 }

Comment: I've literally stripped everything out except what you suggested.  It's very strange.

Comment: I don't know what would be causing that error. You may want to start a new question to ask about it, since it's sort of off-topic for the original question at hand. Your widgets are showing up correctly, getting them to communicate to the server is your problem now. (I promise it's possible, I've done it, I just don't know why you'd get that stack trace)

Comment: For anyone trying to do this, I used the approach outlined in this doc and it worked perfectly: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/Xsite

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do it now. But in the future you can use [Web Components](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webcomponents/raw-file/tip/explainer/index.html) to do that.

But there's the possibility to export a GWT/Java API using [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/). That makes it possible to automatically create a JavaScript API. [gwtchismes](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/) uses this to export a [JavaScript version of GWT widgets](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/JsChismes_Documentation). You can find a tutorial about it in [their wiki](http://code.google.com/p/gwtchismes/wiki/Tutorial_ExportingGwtLibrariesToJavascript_en).

Comment: This gwt-exporter definitely sounds promising.  I'll have a play with it over the next few days and let you know how I get on.

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans GWT project

**mycss.css:**

```
body, html,div.wrap-frame{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    widht: 100%;
    height: 100%;}body{
    background: white;
}

.row1or3 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.row2{
    width: 100%;
    height: 80%;
    background: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    display:flex;
}

.wrapper{
   width:100%;
   height: 100%;
}

.box{
    float:left; 
    height: 100%;
}

.box:nth-child(1){
    width:25%;
    background-color:red;
}

.box:nth-child(2){
    width:50%;
    background-color:green;
}

.box:nth-child(3){
    width:25%;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**welcomeGWT.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script id=ft type="text/javascript"  src="org.yournamehere.Main/org.yournamehere.Main.nocache.js"></script>
    <meta name='gwt:module' content='org.yournamehere.Main=org.yournamehere.Main'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mycss.css"> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row1or3"> Row1
    </div>

    <div class="row2">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="box">
                Left Side Menu
            </div>
            <div class="box" id="mydiv"> 
            </div>
            <div class="box">
                Right Side Menu
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row1or3">
        Row3
    </div>​
</body>
```

**MainEntryPoint.java**

```
public class MainEntryPoint implements EntryPoint {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of MainEntryPoint
 */
public MainEntryPoint() {
}

/**
 * The entry point method, called automatically by loading a module that
 * declares an implementing class as an entry-point
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
    final Label label = new Label("Hello, GWT!!!");
    final Button button = new Button("Click me!");

    button.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            label.setVisible(!label.isVisible());
        }
    });

    RootPanel root = RootPanel.get("mydiv");
   root.add(button);
    root.add(label);
}
}
```

[image]

Now you can name any div element of any html page  as  id=mydiv and add the compiled GWT jscript.
I have tested.